# Is the apex job id always unique?

Tags: apex, batch

I am working on a batch system to create a massive number of entries and the system should be able to remove all the created entries if one of the chunks of the batch fails.

I will add to every created entry the apex job id of the batch so that I know which entries to remove.

By definition, the id's are always unique; however, I want to be 100% sure that the apex job id's for each job will be always unique.

**Is the apex job id always unique?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Job Id for each batch is unique. If this were not so, then System.abortJob could inadvertently kill more than one job, which is typically undesirable.

Comment: so salesforce for the job ids will never start counting from 0. Right? I am also considering the job ids of the batches that were already processed.

Comment: @Cubancoffee The 0 Id (formally 000000000000000AAA) is called the NULL Id, and is used to indicate that there is no value (e.g. in a lookup field). The job Id will never contain this value, so yes, it is safe to say that no job Id will ever be 0.